# Catch ConnectException from Guzzle

Tags: php, guzzle

I am trying to retrieve the error message that comes with a GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException in Guzzle 6.
I read that in older version this could be achieved with getResponse().
However, the method now returns null by default.

This is my code:

```
$responses = Pool::batch($client, $requests($this->list), array(
    'concurrency' => 15,
));

foreach ($responses as $event) {
    $classname = get_class($event);
    $raw = print_r($event,1);
    if ($classname == "GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException") {
        $response = json_encode((string)$event->getResponse());
    }
    echo $response;
  }
```

$response is empty.
However, $raw contains these lines:

```
[0] => GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException Object
    (
        [request:GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException:private] => GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request Object
            (
                [method:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request:private] => GET
                ....
            )

        [response:GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException:private] => 
        [handlerContext:GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException:private] => Array
            (
                [errno] => 6
                [error] => Could not resolve host: mydomain.it
                [url] => http://mydomain.it/
                [content_type] => 
                [http_code] => 0
                ....
```

How do I retrieve the "Could not resolve host: mydomain.it" message?
All I found was "you need to catch the error". But how when I am using Pool::batch and everything already is in my responses array?

Answer (score 4):

Use `$event->getMessage()` (Exception Message) instead of `$event->getResponse()` because there is no connection, so no response